# flat file source order of columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a flat file source as

SOURCE1~SOURCE2~SOURCE3

1~2~3

1~2~3
target is

1~2~3

1~2~3

which is normal case.

now the scenario as my extract has changes to

SOUCE2~SOURCE1~SOURCE3

1~2~3

1~2~3

now the target is still

1~2~3

1~2~3

but needs to get as

2~1~3

2~1~3

the data in the target table is not dynamically getting.

the target is

it is not following the header names.

Could I get any information on changing the order of columns in .txt files.

thanks
prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection manager in SSIS is not dynamic.  Once the connection manager is defined, the order of columns determines the mapping into the data flow.  You will need to modify the package for the new layout.

Comment: Yes, I did some research on the dynamic mapping of columns in SSIS. Unfortunately SSIS don't support this dynamic nature on connections. thnaks prav

Comment: @praveen You could make a custom data source script to handle order variation